# RevMob banner does not hide

Tags: ios, revmob, revmobads

I'm trying to use RevMob ([Link to RevMob](http://www.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/)) as alternative for Admob.

Now it is working, but not quite well. I only want a banner on some views. But the `[[Thing session] hideBanner]` isn't working seems to me. Does anyone have this also?

Or eventually an other Ad network that has a high filtrate ?

Kind Regards

Comment: What method do you use to show the banner?

Comment: I used the SDK methods for it. Now I am using iAd but the filtrate isn't that great.